# CORS блокирует POST запросы, когда GET работает

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

1)Поднял локальный сервер на Express он слушает 3002 порт
2)Vue SLI стоит на порту 8080
Вполне логично что Cors будет блокировать запросы на разных постах, он так и делал.
Я прописал на GET запрос
`res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:8080")`
и все работает.
вот слушатель

```js
app.get('/api/lessonse', (req, res) => {
   console.log("получил данные")
   res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:8080")
   res.status(200)
   const getLessonse = async () => {
      try {
         await client.connect()
         console.log("Подключен к БД")
         lessonse = client.db().collection('lessonse')
         const lessonseArr = await lessonse.find().toArray();
         res.send(JSON.stringify(lessonseArr))


      }
      catch (e) {
         console.log(e)
      }

   }
   getLessonse()


})
```

Как только я попробовал проделать тоже самое с POST запросом, CORS ругается и не дает отправить данные

слушатель

```js
app.post('/api/lessonsee', (req, res) => {
   res.status(200)
   res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:8080")
   res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
   console.log("получил данные")
})
```

Браузер выдает ошибку

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сам запрос во  vue

```js
 async save() {
      for (let i = 0; i < this.$refs.less.length; i++) {
        this.$refs.less[0].pushLesson();
      }

      let res = await fetch("http://localhost:3002/api/lessonse", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(),
      });
      let result = await response.json(this.newLessonseArrData);
      console.log(result.message);
    },
```

В чем моя проблема и почему так происходит? Если хедеры прописаны и работает только с GET? А POST Не пропускает?!

Answer (score 1):

Помогло установка middleware cors :)

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.options('*', cors());
```

Comment: Не забудьте пометить этот ответ как верный, если он Вам помог ;)